# Unity WWW Windows Store Error works for HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am developing an application for the Microsoft Hololens using Unity 5.4. I was attempting to submit a web request using the WWW class (documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)). My code in C# for the WWW request essentially looks like the following:

```
string requestURL = "https://example.com";
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("field_name", "field_value"); //added bc Unity doesn't support empty posts

// Add authorization header
string authorizationInfo = user_id + ":" + user_token;
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authInfo));
Dictionary <string,string> headers = form.headers;
headers["authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

// Submit Request
WWW www = new WWW(requestURL, form.data, headers);
```

The request is always successfully submitted in the Unity editor (the server responds with the desired information). However, when I deploy to the Hololens, it only works if `requestURL` uses HTTP protocol. When `requestURL` uses HTTPS there appears to be no response from the server. Is there any reason why this is and does anybody know how I could make this work for HTTPS? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"When requestURL uses HTTPS there appears to be no response from the server"* - this to me, suggests that whatever server you're sending the request only accepts HTTP and does not have their API running on SSL - hence why it only works over HTTP. Do you have any control over the API you're calling? I think you've kind of answered your own question...

Comment: I'm using Octoblu's API. See their documentation [here](https://octoblu-api.readme.io/docs/testinput). I know it works with HTTPS because all their examples use it and I successfully get the desired response from the server in the Unity editor if I use HTTPS. The same works if I were to just create a small project in Visual Studio and run code similar to that above.

Comment: I see. *"When requestURL uses HTTPS there appears to be no response from the server"* - do you get an exception or anything similar to give you this conclusion?

Comment: Yeah, www.error is populated with the error code 0x800c0008. However, I just realized that the WWW class is only included in documentation for Unity 5.3. It appears that if I use UnityWebRequest (the 5.4 equivalent) with a WWWForm that it works with HTTPS as well. So I think this will work.

Comment: There you go! Answered your own question :) happy coding!